# extracting a certain "set-cookie" value when multiples are returned in response headers

Tags: python, python-requests, response-headers

I am using requests and I need to extract a certain value from response headers set cookie. I cant use r.cookies because that doesnt add expiration, path, domain, etc and I need those values.

When I do

```
test = r.headers['set-cookie']
print(test)
```

I get a response as so:

```
'cookie1 = cookie1value; expires=datehere; path=/; domain=domainhere, cookie2 = cookie2value; expires=datehere; path=/; domain=domainhere,cookie3 = cookie3value; Domain=.domain.com; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 04 Nov 2020 19:44:17 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; Secure
```

I need to extract the value of cookie3 with all of its tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use re

```
import re

test = 'cookie1 = cookie1value; expires=datehere; path=/; domain=domainhere, cookie2 = cookie2value; expires=datehere; path=/; domain=domainhere,cookie3 = cookie3value; expires=datehere; path=/; domain=domainhere,cookie4 = cookie4value; expires=datehere; path=/; domain=domainhere'

p = re.compile(r'cookie3 = (.*)')
print(p.findall(test)[0])
```

Comment: This worked great on my macbook! But for some reason on my PC it cut off after "Expires = Wed" 

I appologize I didnt realize there were more tags after domain. here is all the tags that are after cookie3=value3  Domain=domainhere; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 04 Nov 2020 13:27:01 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; Secure

Comment: so what's the actual full string?

Comment: Sorry for late response, I have updated the string thats printed from headers. I removed Cookie4 as that also was an accident. the correct string is now updated in the original post.